# Public class implementing runnable won't start-Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-listview

When i click on an item in my listview, I would like to have a new thread start and execute the desired tasks I have defined for it in the Connect2 class, however, as far as I can tell the thread is not starting or showing any indication of as why it isn't starting. If anybody could help diagnose a problem in the code or point me in the right direction to fix this issue I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_directory);





    final ListView fileDirectory=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.DirectoryView);
    final ArrayAdapter adapter=new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, SocketConnection.remoteList);
    fileDirectory.setAdapter(adapter);


    fileDirectory.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(FileDirectory.this, "The click works", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FileDirectory.listItem=i;
            new Connect2().execute("");

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    });
}
public class Connect2 extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        runConnectCode();
        return null;
    }
}
public void runConnectCode(){
        String itemTemp=SocketConnection.remoteList.toArray()[FileDirectory.listItem].toString();

            SocketConnection.PW.write(itemTemp);
            //SocketConnection.DOS.flush();


            SocketConnection.currentF.concat("\\"+itemTemp);
            SocketConnection.PW.write(SocketConnection.currentF);
            //SocketConnection.DOS.flush();
        try{
            Object object=SocketConnection.OIS.readObject();
            SocketConnection.remoteList=(ArrayList<String>) object;
        } catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println(e);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }//run()
```

Comment: `System.out` doesn't necessarily go anywhere. Use `System.err` or even better, `android.util.Log``

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your thread using runOnUiThread();

Comment: If i run it on the UI thread it will stall and force the program to close. Thats why im trying to run it on a separate background thread.

Comment: What about using Asynctask ?!

Comment: i don't completely understand how async task works, how would i set that up for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create class extend Asynctask and call your code in doinbackground() method like this:

```
public class Connect2 extends AsyncTask<String , String , String>

{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        runConnectCode();
        return null;
    }

}

public void runConnectCode ()
{
    String itemTemp = SocketConnection.remoteList.toArray()    [FileDirectory.listItem].toString();
    try {
      SocketConnection.DOS.writeUTF(itemTemp);
      SocketConnection.DOS.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    try {
      SocketConnection.currentF.concat("\\" + itemTemp);
      SocketConnection.DOS.writeUTF(SocketConnection.currentF);
      SocketConnection.DOS.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    try {
      Object object = SocketConnection.OIS.readObject();
      SocketConnection.remoteList = (ArrayList<String>) object;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Finally, call this whenever you want:

```
new Connect2().execute("");
```

Comment: can you post your code after adding AsynckTask.? @user3385039

Comment: You should call "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()" in onPostExcute of the AsynckTask.